# Should I use Share Extension of Action Extension?

Tags: ios, ios8-extension

I've create a share extension for iOS that allows sharing files from safari, mail, drive, box & dropbox into my app. However I've discovered action extensions and now I'm thinking I might of been better off using them. Are share extensions meant to be for sharing to social networks etc? Should I be using an action extension for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Share extensions are suitable when there is no need to edit the content or return a result to the app, kinda of like an one-way traffic. It need not be for social networks.

Action extensions are more appropriate when the contents need to be edited, processed, transformed etc and returned to the app.

For your use case, a share extension is the more suitable choice.